# PostGis search query on hstore tags

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query

I am writing a search client, to query postgis db.

The search query will be,

```
SELECT tags->'name' AS name,ST_Transform(way,4326) AS pt_lonlattext FROM planet_osm_point WHERE lower(tags->'name') LIKE '%school%'
```

Now, I need the results in such a way that,

fully matched results should be given priority than partially matched ones.

Is there a way to re-construct the above query to get the desired results?

Comment: Not an exact answer but may be http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/sort-by-match-of-like can help you